# How to implement this operator in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, operators

I am interested to implement this operator:

$$(\ln D)[f] =\left(\frac{i \pi}{2}-\gamma\right)  f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x-x'}-\frac{1}{| x-x'| }\right)\,f(x')\,dx'$$

The second term is problematic. Any suggestions?

P.S.
Some [expected outputs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5978):

$\begin{align*}
(\ln D) 1 & {}= -\ln x -\gamma \\
(\ln D) x^n & {}= x^n (\psi (n+1)-\ln x) \\
(\ln D) \ln x & {}= -\zeta(2) -(\gamma+\ln x)\ln x.
\end{align*}$

Comment: What's $\gamma$ supposed to be?

Comment: @J.M. Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expected output for **at least one** specific input function `f`

Comment: Also probably need to specify Principal Value as in:  Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True].   Perhaps start by coding the second term with this construct.

Comment: @BobHanlon done.

Comment: Does that integral have a principal value? Those arise from symmetric limits that allow infinite parts to cancel. It looks like you will lose that effect in a neighborhood of `x` when you subtract off that absolute value term. For example, take `f` to be the identity function (or a constant function).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I took this expression from this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/382738/10059

Comment: @DanielLichtblau this also was my thought

Comment: It is possible that formulation was wrong. I realize that would violate the FLI (Fundamental Law of the Internet), which states, loosely speaking, that nobody can ever post something incorrect. But it is said that there have been sporadic exceptions...

Comment: There are no integrals in [the linked article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5978) at all. These integrals appear in [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382735/whats-the-matrix-of-logarithm-of-derivative-operator-ln-d-what-is-the-rol/382738#382738) which is very doubtful.

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Limit[(n!*x^(n - \[Nu])/Gamma[n - \[Nu] + 1] - 1)/\[Nu], \[Nu] -> 0, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0]` results in `Indeterminate` and does not confirm (6) from the linked article = =your second expected output .

Comment: @Anixx: Are you seriuos? There are no matrices in the article you refer to.

Comment: @user64494 I look at the Taylor series in (9). Insert monomials and get the matrix

Comment: @Anixx: Can you kindly elaborate your comment? How to insert monomials in $−(\gamma + \ln x) f(x) +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n h_n x^n} {n!}$, where $h_n$ stands for the harmonic number? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 $\psi(n+1)=h_n-\gamma$, see (7). So we take $\gamma  f(x)$ from the second term, and get $− \ln x f(x) +\sum_{n!}^\infty \frac {a_n \psi(n+1) x^n} {n!}$. Inserting $a_n$ for monomials, we get $(\ln D)1=-\ln x +\psi(1)$, $(\ln D)x=(-\ln x +\psi(2))x$, $(\ln D)x^2=(-\ln x +\psi(3))x^2$ etc, which coincdes with their examples.

Comment: @user64494 But taking exponent of that operator does not result in derivative operator, so I think the article is wrong.

Comment: @user64494 well, I obtained the same result as in the article using this Mathematica code: Table[DSolveValue[{f'[x] + s f[x] == x^n, f[0] == 0}, f[x], x] // 
  FullSimplify, {n, 0, 5}]
Integrate[%, s] // FullSimplify
Limit[%, s -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify
Table[Coefficient[%, x, k], {k, 0, 5}] // Expand // MatrixForm

Comment: $(\ln D)[f]=-\ln (x)+\left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}  \psi (1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdot  \\  0 & \psi (2) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdot  \\  0 & 0 & \psi (3) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdot  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & \psi (4) & 0 & 0 & \cdot  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \psi (5) & 0 & \cdot  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \psi (6) & \cdot  \\  \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot  \\ \end{array} \right)$